# How to align button to text area

Tags: javascript, html, alignment

As you can see in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3spqLzx1/1/ 
I would like to align vertically (on the same line) my text area with my button, but the button keeps on being pushed downwards. Could you please tell me a way to make them align? Thank you

Text area + Button HTML

```
<p id="headings"><textarea name="msg" style="height:40px;text-align:center"  id="message" placeholder="Insert your message here"></textarea></p>
<p id="button"><input type="button" value="Send" onclick="submitChat()"    id="innerbutton"></p>
```

CSS

```
#headings {
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
width:70% !important;
margin-top:20px;
}
#headings {
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
width:70% !important;
margin-top:20px;
}
#message {
width:100%;
}
#button {
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
width:8%;
margin-top:-30px !important;
border:solid black;
height:50px;
}
#innerbutton {
width:100%;
height:50px;
margin-top:25px;
background-color:rgb(22, 33, 211);
text-decoration:none;
margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the display:flex and the alignment system. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

Comment: there are better ways to build the html, but this should be helpful:

https://jsfiddle.net/3spqLzx1/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the changes:

```
#innerbutton {
...
-margin-top: 25px;
...
}


#button {
...
- margin-top:-30px !important;
+ vertical-align: top;
...
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3spqLzx1/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#headings {
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
width:70% !important;
margin-top:20px;
}
#message {
width:100%;

}
#button {
 position:absolute; 
margin-top:20px;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
width:8%;
margin-top:20px !important;
border:solid black;
height:50px;
}
#innerbutton {
  
width:100%;
height:50px;
margin-top:0px;
background-color:rgb(22, 33, 211);
text-decoration:none;

}
```

```html
<div id="messagebox">
<p id="headings"><textarea name="msg" style="height:40px;text-align:center" id="message" placeholder="Insert your message here"></textarea></p>
<p id="button"><input type="button" value="Send" onclick="submitChat()" id="innerbutton"></p>
</div>
```